# Struggling to get AI to repeat infinitely

Tags: java, ai

I am following this as a guideline to help me figure out a simple AI for an enemy as I am new to java.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/08/game-ai-an-introduction-to-behaviour-trees.html

https://github.com/obviam/behavior-trees/tree/master/src/net/obviam/bt

I am calling this function:

```
AI goombaBrain = Routines.selector(Routines.repeatInfinite(Routines.wander(Board.board, InitObject.goomba)));

InitObject.goomba.setRoutine(goombaBrain);
```

But once it finishes wandering to a random location once it doesn't automatically reset. Any ideas? if you need any more information let me know. (InitObject.goomba is the enemy)

Answer (score 2):

I've done some code reading and now it's obvious...

you do the following with your code:

1. create a wander `Routine`
2. create a repeatInfinite `Routine` for the wander `Routine`
3. create a selector `Routine` for the repeatInfinite Routine

so far so good - but if you read the code for the [`Selector`](https://github.com/obviam/behavior-trees/blob/master/src/net/obviam/bt/ai/Selector.java) (the selector `Routine`) you'll notice the  following:

```
// We need to progress the sequence. If there are no more routines
// then the state is the last routine's state. (Success for OR was already handled)
if (routineQueue.peek() == null) {
    this.state = currentRoutine.getState();
} else {
    currentRoutine = routineQueue.poll();
    currentRoutine.start();
}
```

this part of the code will **REMOVE** the *repeatInfinite Routine for the wander Routine* from the selector Queue and hence it will be no longer executed. See [LinkedList.poll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#poll()) for details.

### Solution

if you really want to infinitely execute the *repeatInfinite Routine for the wander Routine* then you have to do it solely, without the selector:

```
AI goombaBrain =  Routines.repeatInfinite(Routines.wander(Board.board, InitObject.goomba));
InitObject.goomba.setRoutine(goombaBrain);
```

Comment: Hmm still not working. I realized something though, the Wander routine never is properly finished, it just activates the MoveTo and that finishes but the wander routine is never told it succeeded/failed so it never resets. any ideas? unless I misunderstand what it means

Comment: WAIT I was missing some code in Wander!!!! But thanks for your fix anyway, even if I had found my error it still wouldnt have been working but now it is thanks to you :D